# Symbol for 'equally likely/probable'

Tags: notation, logic

I'm looking for the 'mathematical' symbol, if it exists, that denotes 'equally likely'. For example, one has two potential outcomes from a present state, both of which are equally likely (or probable). Is there a symbol for that?

Comment: Won't "$=$" do, when suitably applied?

Comment: I agree with @whuber.  You usually see P(outcome A | current state) = P(outcome B | current state).  It is more of a mathematical statement than a symbol.

Comment: @RCarnell, why not turn your comment into an official answer? That way this thread won't count as unanswered.

Comment: Couple distinctions: are the two outcomes complementary like heads versus tails on a fair coin? Also you mention "state", is this *actually* a dynamical system state (that is otherwise random) or more simply an assumption (like that the coin is in fact fair)?

Answer (score 6):

In statistics we normally say

$$P(\text{Event A} | \text{current state}) = P(\text{Event B} | \text{current state})$$
to denote outcomes that are equally probable.

Comment: Actually, probabilities are assigned to *events* rather than outcomes.

Comment: Edited.  In some ways, outcomes are a specific type of event.  I like the more general "event".